# Why my ISP can't change my IP address?

Tags: internet, internet-connection, ip-address

My ISP is using dynamic IP addresses, now I have problems with my IP (it seems to be blocked somewhere) and want it to be changed. My ISP says to me that they can't assign a new IP for me, can that be true? I have powered off my cable modem for over 10 hours but when I turn it on I get the same IP address.

Comment: Have you tried releasing and renewing your IP address on your computer or router?

Comment: Does no good for his IP with the ISP.

Comment: Are you sure it's a Dynamic IP Address?

Comment: @slhck - Any idea why this question was closed as off-topic? Isn't a modem or perhaps a router considered computer hardware?

Comment: @Pekka Tiira - you didn't mention who your ISP is, and if your setup includes a router. If you use a router, you can probably get a new IP address by **`spoofing`** the MAC address in your router. That is, to copy the MAC address from your PC into your router.

Comment: @Kevin Networking questions about problems with a modem etc are fine, but this question is only about the ISP and whether they assign a new address or not, which nobody except the ISP themselves can do anything about.

Answer (score 6):

Your ISP wants it both ways. They reserve the right to have your IP address change dynamically (as new customers are added or their network is reconfigured). They also don't want to give you a static IP. And they don't want to support manually changing your IP due to it being a hassle for them.

You might be able to use a proxy (something like TOR) to access the site but probably better to contact the site owner and resolve what got you banned.

I wouldn't hold much hope on your ISP changing your address for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so I must find away myself to get a new IP-address. I will release the IP-address and power off the modem/router for a week :D perhaps that will do the trick?

Comment: You aren't going to get a new IP, you are going to bypass the site's filtering. This doesn't actually resolve anything its getting around. It also doesn't really sound like your blocked from anything per your reponse to me below

Comment: I think you are better served trying to solve the root problem. Can you access the site from another computer (or something like a phone)?

Comment: Yes I can access the site if I use my wife's phone (other ISP) or if I use other cable modem/router because then I get another IP-address.

Comment: Please add all relevant information where it belongs, in the question above. Be thorough so we can have the required information and go from there.

Comment: My ISP is DNA in Finland my site (pekka.tiira.net) is hosted by lpwebhosting.com in California USA.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it *could* be true. From the standpoint that the impact of forcing the entire network to re-lease its IPs could outweigh the benefit of fixing your issues.

As for it being blocked, they don't know for a fact that you did not get banned from a forum, or blocked from a website for doing things you shouldn't. It really is up to you to find a way to contact any sites that are blocking you and attempt to get the ban released.

Comment: Well as far as I know I'm not banned anywhere and the only website I can't access is my own site! And I'm not blocked there at least that is what have been told to me.

Comment: Internal site? Where is this site? There really should be alot more information in your question then. What error are you getting? Why would you think you are blocked? etc. etc. etc..

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't access my own website"?

Comment: If I try to get my home page I get "timed out" error, I can't use cPanel, use my email, ftp is not working.

Comment: I live in Finland my site is hosted by a company in California.

Comment: And why do you want to change your IP? Have you tried from a different IP (3G connection from your smartphone)?

Comment: Check if the home page is accessible by http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: I want to change my IP because everything works fine with other IP's but the one I have.

Comment: What about another PC on your modem? What if you bypass any router? Boot from a linux live disk, same issue? How do you know your time with the IP did not block it? Maybe a neighbor leached off you and did something and a new IP would only block it again? Have you contacted your web host and asked why your blocked or if you are at their level? Did you accidently block yourself somehow when maintaining your site? As it stands now your question has been answered, "Why my ISP can't change my IP address?". I think you either need a serious rework or a new question with ALL the info you have.

Comment: How did you check it works with other IP addresses?

Answer (score 0):

Of course they can - well, not the first level support guys you are speaking to - but they don't want to.

Why would they want to have people banned from whatever forum calling them the whole day to get their IP changed? Also what would they do with all the IP addresses banned all over the place?

Comment: He's asking "My ISP says to me that they can't assign a new IP for me, can that be true?", so actually it is.

Comment: So now you remove your comment saying "It's not an answer to the question." and you downvote? Really nice of you.

Comment: I have not removed anything or downvoted!

Comment: I didn't mean you, sorry it wasn't clear. Some guy did, don't remember his nick.

Comment: @user2210761 - ***"so actually it is"***. Just because ISP said **`can't`** doesn't mean they actually ***can't***. Most likely they can but just don't want to.

Comment: @Kevin Fegan : That's what I said. This comment was replying to another one (now deleted) saying the answer was not answering the question.

Comment: @user2210761 - funny how that keeps happening to me lately... never mind =)